# A django field with two fields. Need opinion

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

There is a scenario where I want to store two types of information for a field. For example, consider a field namely "name". This field should two types of the following information:-

1. Boolean - to store whether the user wants this field to be shown or not.
2. Label - if the user wants to change the label to show.

I was wondering to solve this by using a model. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes creating a new model for you "name" field will work fine if you don't want to add both fields separately in your parent table

Answer (score 0):

You can define fields on other model and use them with genericForeignKey